# passing multiple arguments to function php

Tags: php, function

Apologies for the newbie question but i have a function that takes two parameters one is an array one is a variable `function createList($array, $var) {}`. I have another function which calls createList with only one parameter, the $var, `doSomething($var);` it does not contain a local copy of the array. How can I just pass in one parameter to a function which expects two in PHP?

### attempt at solution :

```
function createList (array $args = array()) {
    //how do i define the array without iterating through it?
 $args += $array; 
 $args += $var;


}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

First is to use optional parameters.

```
  function myFunction($needThis, $needThisToo, $optional=null) {
    /** do something cool **/
  }
```

The other way is just to avoid naming any parameters (this method is not preferred because editors can't hint at anything and there is no documentation in the method signature).

```
 function myFunction() {
      $args = func_get_args();

      /** now you can access these as $args[0], $args[1] **/
 }
```

Comment: Awesome did not know  you can set a parameter to null thanks!

Answer (score 59):

If you can get your hands on PHP 5.6+, there's a new syntax for variable arguments: the ellipsis keyword.
It simply converts all the arguments to an array.

```
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}
echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Doc: [... in PHP 5.6+](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is advantageous because [you can now type hint a variable number of arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-176), as the accepted answer mentions that is a huge downside of `func_get_args()`

Answer (score 4):

You can specify no parameters in your function declaration, then use PHP's [func_get_arg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) or [func_get_args](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to get the arguments.

```
function createList() {
   $arg1 = func_get_arg(0);
   //Do some type checking to see which argument it is.
   //check if there is another argument with func_num_args.
   //Do something with the second arg.
}
```